# Difference between User models

Tags: python, django

I'm learning django now, watch tutorials. The questions is: What is the difference between using:

`from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model User = get_user_model()`

`User = get_user_model()`

and
`from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

I've seen both of them and both of them used in model with ForeignKey, but I don't know the difference between these two
model, for example:

````
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='posts'
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField()```
````

Answer (score 1):

The [**`get_user_model()`** function <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model) will return a reference to the class that you set in the [**`AUTH_USER_MODEL`** setting <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL). By default this is `'auth.User'`, so the model of the `django.contrib.auth.models` module, but you can specify a different user model.

It is however better to make use of the `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` to refer to the user model, than to use `User` or `get_user_model()`, as is specified in the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model), you thus work with:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='posts'
    )
    # …
```